# There are AlamManager, SmsManager etc. in Android. Is there also a Manager for managing calls?

Tags: android, call, alarmmanager, smsmanager

In Android there are AlamManager:

```
AlarmManager alarmanager = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
alarmanager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,System.currentTimeMillis()+(i*1000),pendingIntent);
```

and SmsManager:

```
SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
smsManager.sendTextMessage(senderNumber, null, "Sorry, I'm kind of busy right now, call u l8r.", null, null);
```

and so on. I would like to manage calls? Is there also something like 'CallManager'?

Comment: What would you want to achieve with such a component?

Comment: There is a `TelephonyManager`: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're probably looking for [TelephonyManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager.html)